# Twitter Like Character counter - fixed count for links

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have a Social Media Product from which I can tweet. 
The javascript counter I use works as follows.

```
angular.module('starter.message-controller', [])
    .controller('MessageController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        'use strict';

        var _this = this || {};
        var local = $scope.messageCtrl;

        local.remainingCount = 0;
        local.remainingCountClass = '';

        local.countRemaining = function() {
            var style, 
                c = (_this.description_value ? _this.description_value.length : 0),
                h = (_.isEmpty(_this.hashtags_value) ? 0 : _this.hashtags_value.length + 1);

            c = c + h;
            style = 'label';

            if ((c > 0) && (c <= 60)) {
                style = 'label label-success';
            } else if ((c > 60) && (c <= 100)) {
                style = 'label label-warning';
            } else if (c > 100) {
                style = 'label label-important';
            }

            local.remainingCount = c;
            local.remainingCountClass = style;
        };

        _this.updateMessageView = function(e, desc, hash) {
            angular.element(description).val(desc);

            if (window.hashtags) {          
                angular.element(hashtags).val(hash);
            }

            local.countRemaining();
        };

        $rootScope.$on('updateMessageView', _this.updateMessageView);

    });
```

The problem I have is when I add a link. 
It will count the real character count and not the 22 characters that twitter sets it too.

Is there a way how I can make it recognize a link and give it a value of 22 characters.

Comment: Twitter links actually 22 characters since it shortens them to `http://t.co/somethingg`

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Instead of the 30 odd characters have it count only 22

Comment: IDK if Twitter API shorten your URL and then checks for 140 chars limit or any other API call to shorten URL before send a tweet to them but if you want to see links as 22 chars for counting use regular expression to catch URLs. I can't link any of them but there are tons of answered questions for that.